# Azure MariaDB returns wrong column datatypes

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, mariadb

We are using MariaDB (both local on promise and Azure MariaDB) with EntityFramework 6.
However, we got the error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: The requested column value could not be treated as or conveted to a Guid.

while performing a query including some joins and unions (come from the "Include" statement of EF).

I tried to get the generated SQL query and run it on a sql client (HeidiSQL). it showed that:
[image]

The right side is the result from Azure MariaDB, all VARCHAR fields were converted automatically to VARBINARY (and same for other fields) which causes a wrong type casting in the MySql.Data lib.

I guess there must be some configuration on Azure MariaDB, do you have any idea about it?